# How to add if statement to record

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

How do I add if statement inside this record?

```
CorpData.Address viewAddress = new CorpData.Address
        {
            DocumentId = lblDocId.Text.ToUpper(),

            Address =  txtAddress.Text.ToUpper(),
            AddressCity = txtCity.Text.ToUpper(),
            AddressZip = txtZip.Text.ToUpper(),
            StateCode = statesDropdown.SelectedValue,
        };
```

I am trying to add an if statement to check if stateCode in the US

Comment: Your problem is not entirely clear to me. Please reformulate your problem...

Comment: Are you looking for the ternary operator `? :` ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with an `if` statement?

Comment: you can't. you could use a ternary, e.g. `statecode = (selectedvalue = 'american') ? 'yep' : 'nope')`-type thing.

Comment: I am trying to do this inside that block
`if (statesDropdown.SelectedValue !=  "US"){
      StateCode = statesDropdown.SelectedValue,
}else{   
StateCode = countryDropdown.SelectedValue
}`

Comment: As stated before, check out the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use a ternary operator on the property assignment:

`StateCode = IsInUs(statesDropdown.SelectedValue)? statesDropdown.SelectedValue : string.empty`

And then create a new method to perform the test. Something like:

```
private static bool IsInUs(string testValue){
    If(ListOfStateCodes.Contains(testValue))
        return True;
    return False;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan! that what I was looking for.